# Using Web Server for Maven Site

Tags: apache, maven, tomcat, httpserver, maven-site-plugin

We are currently moving from Nexus 2 to Artifactory.

While Nexus 2 had dedicated support for Maven Sites, Artifactory has not.

I guess that I could deploy Maven Sites to an Apache HTTP Server, a Tomcat or anything similar, but I am not sure.

What are the prerequisites for using a server as a "Maven Site server"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work:

- Install a Apache httpd on a Linux system. Configure the www directory.
- Use `scp` to deploy the site to the defined www directory.

For `scp`, you need the wagon dependency for ssh and an appropriate user for your Linux server.

Comment: I have a similar need, googles not much help with the very vague search terms I could come up with - is there anything you might have found thats an opensource project that is basically "ready to go", e.g. no or little configuration?

Comment: @JGlass No, I just used the Apache httpd.

Comment: Glad you got it going!  I ended up using Nexus.  It supported it out of the box (thank you for the hint)!  Doesnt help a ton in that we are slowly moving to MicroSoft DevOps - which doesnt use Nexus O_o, hence our problem.